# составной словарь из двух списков

Tags: dict, value

Есть два списка:

```
animals=[lion,dog,dog]
id=[0042,0043,0003]
```

На выходе нужно получить словарь:

```
{'dog':[0003,0043],'lion':0042}
```

Сортировка ключей по длине слова, а значений - по возрастанию

Answer (score 0):

поставил в id строки просто чтобы сохранить вид с нулями в начале

```
animals = ['lion', 'dog', 'dog']
id = ['0042','0043','0003']

# собрать словарь
res = dict()

for obj in zip(animals, id):
    res[obj[0]] = res.get(obj[0], []) # если в словаре отсутствует ключ - создать запись с пустым списком
    res[obj[0]].append(obj[1]) # добавить в список новый элемент

# отсортировать значения словаря
for key in res:
    res[key].sort()

print(res)
```